# Unable to get list of files when specifying folder ID of google drive using python

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-api-python-client

I am unable to get list of files present in my google drive folder as I am providing folder ID. The same code works fine when I am using my personal credentials but when I use my official it give me blank list. insertion deletion of files works fine when using my official credentials.

```
query = f"'{folder_ids}' in parents"
        name_response = service.files().list(q = f"parents in '{'MY FOLDER ID'}'").execute()
        
        files = name_response.get('files')
        nextPageToken = name_response.get('nextPageToken')
```

OUTPUT:

> {'kind': 'drive#fileList', 'incompleteSearch': False, 'files': []}

Comment: Looks like its working to me if you had pass the wrong folderid you would have gotten a 404 error or a 400 error.   Looks to me like there are no files in that directory that the current user has permission to see.

Comment: Are you trying to access the same folder both with your personal and work credentials? Is it a shread folder / on a shared Drive? Empty result usually means that there are no files in this fodler. Check the id.